# How do I escape an HTML element so I can type the term <div> in an HTML write-up

Tags: html, escaping

I'm doing an HTML write up for a colleague that is going to go on our intranet site, but I have to write the instructions in the HTML itself. I need to write the word `<div>` in the instructions, but I need to have it so the '' displays as the word , not an actual div.

Because I'm writing it directly inside the HTML, I need a way of somehow escaping the HTML, but keep the word and it's arrow brackets.

How do I go about doing this?

EXAMPLE

```
<p>This is some text followed by the word <div>, but not an actual div.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` Those are [HTML Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) which can replace real tags. That way, it'll apear as `<div>` althought it isn't actually a div.

```html
<p>This is some text followed by the word &lt;div&gt;, but not an actual div.</p>
```

Comment: @TheChewy It's not a  bad question. Althought it was probably downvoted because there's tons of duplicates. I updvoted it to even it out. I really hate it when people downvote because of duplicates, since some people just can't find the duplicates.